# Drupal menu don't show up when menu based on token menu are fired

Tags: views, routes

I have a menu in a drupal site. All elements was visible until I install "menu-token" module and make two elements based on tokens.
Now when I visit a page linked to a path that point on a views page, the two "token menus" disapear !

Al other menu items are still visible.

Can someone help ?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the [Menu token](https://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module so should be posted to the [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/menu_token?status=All) as opposed to here.

Comment: OK thanks. The token I used was not available on some pages and this made the menu dessappear. Indeed, the link you gave helped me a lot.